# Select in sqlite with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

i have this code to make a sqlite query:

```
db.transaction(function (tx))
{
   tx.executeSql("Select * from DatosRemito where idoperador like " + obj.vac_user_id, [], OnSucess, OnError)
});
```

i have this error Message in my OnError Function when i try to execute my query:

the first line shows me the content in "obj.vac_user_id" variable
[image]

what do i am doing bad?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have missed out quotes, your variable is a string:

```
tx.executeSql("Select * from DatosRemito where idoperador like '" + obj.vac_user_id + "'", [], OnSucess, OnError)
```